# Running SQL Server stored procedure(Update)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get the following 2 errors when I want to run the following query in SQL Server 
- how can I resolve the errors? Can you help me?

Run:

```
exec [dbo].[sp_siparisTest] 0,25,'','',''
```

Errors:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
Incorrect syntax near '25'.

```html
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_siparisTest]
(
  @PageNo INT,
  @RowCountPerPage INT,
  @adsoyadfilter NVARCHAR(50),
  @odemetip NVARCHAR(20),
  @durumu NVARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @devam_ nvarchar(max)
SET @devam_ ='SELECT
u.AdiSoyadi as AdSoyad,
ot.Adi as OdemeTipAdi,
sd.Adi as SiparisDurumAdi,
s.OlusturmaTarihi as OlusturmaTarihi,
s.GenelToplam as GenelToplam
FROM
 Siparis as s with(NOLOCK)
inner join 
 SiparisDurum as sd with(NOLOCK) on s.Durumu=sd.Id
inner join 
 Uye as u with(NOLOCK) on s.Uye_Id=u.Id
inner join
 OdemeTip as ot with(NOLOCK) on s.OdemeTip=ot.Id  where ' 
IF(@adsoyadfilter !='') 
 SET @devam_ += '(u.AdiSoyadi LIKE ''%'' + '+ @adsoyadfilter +' + ''%'') AND'
IF(@odemetip != '') 
 SET @devam_ += ' ot.Id IN(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split( '+ @odemetip +' , '','')) AND'
IF(@odemetip != '')
 SET @devam_ += ' s.Durumu IN(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split( '+@durumu +','',''))'
SET @devam_ +=' ORDER BY s.Id OFFSET (' + cast(@PageNo as nvarchar(255)) + ')  ROWS FETCH NEXT (' + cast(@RowCountPerPage as nvarchar(255)) + ') ROWS ONLY'
END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @devam_
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: u should use print @devam_ to show ur error & resolved.

Comment: `@PageN`o and `@RowCountPerPage` have to be concatenated in ...

Comment: `with(NOLOCK)` is not a magic "go fast button", use it wisely. See [this](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: You also have a double `AND` in the last 2 `IF` statements. If `@odemetip = ''` you will have an `AND` before the `ORDER BY`. Both of these scenarios will cause a syntax error. I think you meant in the last `IF` statement to be `IF @durumu != ''`

Comment: You should also use a unicode string instead of ASCII. (`N'SELECT...'`, notice the `N`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your next to last line, change the SET to this:

```
SET @devam_ +=' ORDER BY s.Id OFFSET (' + cast(@PageNo as varchar(64)) + ')  ROWS FETCH NEXT (' + cast(@RowCountPerPage as varchar(64)) + ') ROWS ONLY)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a clause if all params are '' (1=1) and take @RowCountPerPage outside of the string:

```
ALTER PROC sp_siparisTest
(
  @PageNo INT,
  @RowCountPerPage INT,
  @adsoyadfilter NVARCHAR(50),
  @odemetip NVARCHAR(20),
  @durumu NVARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @devam_ nvarchar(max)
SET @devam_ = 'SELECT
u.AdiSoyadi as AdSoyad,
ot.Adi as OdemeTipAdi,
sd.Adi as SiparisDurumAdi,
s.OlusturmaTarihi as OlusturmaTarihi,
s.GenelToplam as GenelToplam
FROM
    Siparis as s with(NOLOCK)
inner join 
    SiparisDurum as sd with(NOLOCK) on s.Durumu=sd.Id
inner join 
    Uye as u with(NOLOCK) on s.Uye_Id=u.Id
inner join
    OdemeTip as ot with(NOLOCK) on s.OdemeTip=ot.Id  where( '

IF(@adsoyadfilter !='') 
    SET @devam_ += '(u.AdiSoyadi LIKE ''%'' + @adsoyadfilter + ''%'') AND'
IF(@odemetip != '') 
    SET @devam_ += ' ot.Id IN(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@odemetip, '','')) AND'
IF(@odemetip != '')
    SET @devam_ += ' AND s.Durumu IN(SELECT Value FROM fn_Split(@durumu,'','')) '

if @adsoyadfilter + @odemetip + @odemetip = '' SET @devam_ += '1=1) '

SET @devam_ +=' ORDER BY s.Id OFFSET (' + cast(@PageNo as nvarchar(255)) + ')  ROWS FETCH NEXT (' + cast(@RowCountPerPage as nvarchar(255)) + ') ROWS ONLY'
END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @devam_
```